# Updating an input field when button clicked not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a small mvc.net web application that takes some input from the user and when the user clicks the button the input data is calculated and displayed in two input fields. However when the button is clicked (see file Index.cshtml) nothing is displayed in the two input fields. Would appreciate any help to figure out what might be wrong. :)

[An image of the web application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjjlT.png)

Here follows my code...

SelectPurchaseModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models
{
    public class SelectPurchaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public double AmountExVat { get; set; }
        public double AmountInVat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Article.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models;

namespace TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //List<Article> articles;

            SelectPurchaseModel model = new SelectPurchaseModel();
            model.Name = "";
            model.Articles = new List<Article>{
                new Article { Name = "Bananas"},
                new Article { Name = "Apples"},
                new Article { Name = "Oranges"},
                new Article { Name = "Melons"},
                new Article { Name = "Grapes"},
                new Article { Name = "Sallad"},
                new Article { Name = "Potatoes"},
                new Article { Name = "Cucumber"},
                new Article { Name = "Beans"},
                new Article { Name = "Tomatoes"}
            };

            model.Quantity = 0;
            model.Price = 0.0;

            model.AmountExVat = 0.0;
            model.AmountInVat = 0.0;

            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Home
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SelectPurchaseModel purchase)
        {
            purchase.Articles = new List<Article>{
                new Article { Name = "Bananas"},
                new Article { Name = "Apples"},
                new Article { Name = "Oranges"},
                new Article { Name = "Melons"},
                new Article { Name = "Grapes"},
                new Article { Name = "Sallad"},
                new Article { Name = "Potatoes"},
                new Article { Name = "Cucumber"},
                new Article { Name = "Beans"},
                new Article { Name = "Tomatoes"}
            };

            purchase.AmountExVat = purchase.Quantity * (purchase.Price - (purchase.Price * 0.10));
            purchase.AmountInVat = purchase.Quantity * (purchase.Price * 1.10);

            return View(purchase); 
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model TheMakingOfAWebApplication.Models.SelectPurchaseModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn btn-default").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var quantity = $("#Quantity").attr('value');
            var price = $("#Price").attr('value');
            var AmountExVat = quantity * (price - (price * 0.10));
            var AmountInVat = quantity * (price * 1.10);

            $("#AmountExVat").val(AmountExVat);
            $("#AmountInVat").val(AmountInVat);
        });
    });


</script>



<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Article</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, new SelectList(Model.Articles, "Name", "Name"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountExVat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmountExVat)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountExVat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountInVat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AmountInVat)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountInVat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </p>

        </fieldset>
        </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Try using `val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

Comment: Change to `var quantity = $("#Quantity").val();` and `var price = $("#Price").val()`;

Comment: Another question - does the js function is invoked?

Comment: Thanks guys. I changed the code to use val() instead, but no improvement. While debugging I could not see that the Js function got called after the button was clicked and I don't understand why it would not be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: use `$(".btn.btn-default")`  instead of `$(".btn btn-default")`

2nd use `.val()` instead of `attr('value');`

3rd you may need to use `parseInt()` or `pareseFloat();`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn.btn-default").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var quantity = $("#Quantity").val();
            var price = $("#Price").val();
            var AmountExVat = quantity * (price - (price * 0.10));
            var AmountInVat = quantity * (price * 1.10);

            $("#AmountExVat").val(AmountExVat);
            $("#AmountInVat").val(AmountInVat);
        });
    });


</script>
```

About using `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`

```
var quantity = parseInt($("#Quantity").val() , 10);
var price = parseFloat($("#Price").val());
```

Additional: if all of that not work ..  you can try

```
$(".btn.btn-default").on('click',function () {
```

or

```
$("body").on('click',".btn.btn-default",function () {
```

Comment: Thanks allot Mohamed-Yousef! So nice! :)
One question, why did I have to write `$(".btn.btn-default")` instead of `$(".btn btn-default")`?

Comment: @patswelund cause btn and btn-default is a classes for the same element  .. if you use .btn .btn-default >> its mean element with class btn has a child element with class .btn-default .. you got it?? (space between them means find child in parent)

Comment: `@Mohamed-Yousef` I got it. Thanks allot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not binding property so fixed as mentioned below and you should use val() instead of attr('value')

```
$(".btn.btn-default").click(function () {
                var quantity = $("#Quantity").val();
                var price = $("#Price").val();
                var amountExVat = quantity * (price - (price * 0.10));
                var amountInVat = quantity * (price * 1.10);

                $("#AmountExVat").val(amountExVat);
                $("#AmountInVat").val(amountInVat);
            });
```

Comment: `@user1672994` Thank you. :)